# Drupal 7 drush - delete / edit views

Tags: views, drush

Drush for Drupal 6 had a plugin that allowed you to delete a view. That plugin's functionality was mostly rolled into drush for Drupal 7.

I have a view that can't be edited through the UI, and I was hoping the drush could solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a Drush command for this, but if you know your view's machine name or ID wiping it from the database isn't too hard.

```
SELECT vid FROM views_view WHERE name = 'your_views_machine_name';
DELETE FROM views_view WHERE vid = id_from_above;
DELETE FROM views_display WHERE vid = id_from_above;
```

That should be the last you ever hear from that view.

Comment: Make sure you also run `drush cc views` after you've run these queries, to clear the views cache.

Answer (score 0):

[Drush Views](http://drupal.org/project/drush_views/) has not been fully incorporated in Views for D7 yet, [supposidely only `drush views-export`](http://drupal.org/node/1096648) works at this time. And, I couldnt get even that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Or without doing a lookup for vid. Find the view id in the url, or html code.

For example in admin/structure/views/view/section_banner, section_banner is the view name.

```
delete views_display from views_display inner join views_view on views_display.vid = views_view.vid where views_view.name =  'view_name';
delete from views_view where name = 'view_name';
```